# Arduino / Telegram Bot, editmessage/button

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Good afternoon. I'm writing a bot for a smart greenhouse on ESP32. I am currently using `bool sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard(Stringchat_id, String text, String parse_mode, String Keyboard)`, but that will send a new message each time. Instead, I would like to update an existing message so that the bot doesn't spam with heaps of messages. How do I do this?

```cpp
{
            if (text == ("LAMP"))
            { // Команды от кнопки (Включение/выключение)
                if (isLightTurned == 0)
                {
                    fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB(255, 255, 255));
                    isLightTurned = 1;
                    FastLED.show();
                    String keyboardJson = "[[{ \"text\" : \"⏪ Назад\", \"callback_data\" : \"TEPLISA\" }]]";
                    bot.sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard(chat_id, "⚪ Освещение включено", "", keyboardJson);
                }
                else if (isLightTurned == 1)
                {
             
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with a "message change function"? Can you please also update your code so that it's a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi. There is a function bot.sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard. But I want him not to send a new message, but to change it, how can I do it?

Comment: I've updated your question to clarify what you're trying to do. Your update to the code example did make it shorter, but now it's not *reproducible*. Please include enough of the code so that someone else can reasonably reproduce what you're doing, and remove the parts that aren't relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are using the [Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot](https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot) library.

While the main reference page on the README doesn't mention how to do this, one of the provided examples ([UpdateInlineKeyboard.ino](https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot/blob/master/examples/ESP32/CustomKeyboard/UpdateInlineKeyboard/UpdateInlineKeyboard.ino)) shows that you can pass in a fifth parameter to `sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard`, with the message ID of the message you'd like to update:

```cpp
// Now send this message including the current message_id as the 5th input to UPDATE that message
bot.sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard(chat_id, msg, "Markdown", keyboardJson, message_id);
```

In [UniversalTelegramBot.h](https://github.com/witnessmenow/Universal-Arduino-Telegram-Bot/blob/master/src/UniversalTelegramBot.h) you can also see that the full signature for the `sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard` method is:

```cpp
bool sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard(const String& chat_id, const String& text,
                                   const String& parse_mode, const String& keyboard, 
                                   int message_id = 0);
```

So, in your scenario, you should obtain the `message_id` of the message you want to update, and use that when calling `sendMessageWithInlineKeyboard`.